# get last messages conversation by username

Tags: php, mysql

Plis help, get last messages conversation!!

database:

```
id,
user_from
user_to
msg
```

query php

```
select * 
from messages 
where 
      user_from = 'Michael' AND 
      user_to = 'Daiana' OR 
      user_from = 'Daiana' AND 
      user_to = 'Michael' 
LEAST(user_to _id, user_from) 
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

Please help me. He's not listing the latest messages in the conversation of the two Daiana and Michael users, as an example.

example result:

- daiana: hello how are yo
- michael: fine and you?
- daiana: fine :)

Comment: type style chat facebook

Comment: why you are not getting record according to created date in desc order?

Comment: I think you should have one more column "Createddatetime". why you want least function here? you can remove least function and increase the limit to get latest records..

Comment: do you get any error ? or are the usernames valid and there is data in database ?

Comment: why don't you get the last conversation by select* from messages order by id desc limit 1

Comment: Try this: select * from messages where (user_from = 'Michael' AND user_to = 'Daiana') OR (user_from = 'Daiana' AND user_to = 'Michael') LEAST(user_to _id, user_from) order by id desc limit 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from messages 
where 
  (user_from = 'Michael' AND user_to = 'Daiana') 
  OR 
  (user_from = 'Daiana' AND user_to = 'Michael' )
LEAST(user_to _id, user_from) 
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Why you want reverse? this query without LEAST... line give you last inserted row. Do you want any thing else?

Comment: It does not work. If I list 5 records then the last message starts aa be the first. And you have to list the messages from the past, like the facebook chat.